# No LED on Junction Box on 2018 di2 8050 - But fully functioning

Tags: shimano-di2

My 2018 di2 8050 is fully functioning as it should. Battery all good holding charge and i can charge battery ok using SM-BCR2.

**Just no lights on junction box** when i hold any gear change lever for 5 sec or when i change gear during use etc.

Recently connected to E-Tube Project on Laptop to perform firmware upgrade and computer suggests all ok - but still no lights on Junction box and gears work perfectly on subsequent  ride.

Look forward to your response and thank you,

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Is there anything you can do to get that light to come on recently? Perhaps the LED (or the circuitry leading to it) has failed? (I know it's not likely to have burned out like a bulb, but the solder joints could fail, etc).